# Get a batch of facebook account images with single graph api call

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my Facebook web app I have to get the profile images of many Facebook accounts ( Only part of them are the user's Facebook friends ). I used the following code to get the information:

```
FB.api(facebookid, {
     fields: "id, name, picture.type(large)"
     }, function (response) {
     if (response && response.picture) {

      } else {

         }
    });
```

The problem is I have to make to many calls to the api so I reached the limit very quickly.

Reference: developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/api-rate-limiting/

Suppose I want to get the profile images and names of 1000 accounts, is it possible to get all these information will a single call instead of 1000 calls?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out I don't need to make a call to get the profile image:

[Get user profile picture by Id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442442/get-user-profile-picture-by-id)