# How to retrieve facebook user profile picture within asp.net core MVC RC2

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, facebook-authentication

Using ASP.NET Core MVC RC2 I am trying to retrieve the Facebook user profile picture. To do this I have the following lines in the Configure method of the Startup class

```
            app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookOptions()
        {
            AppId = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppId"],
            AppSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppSecret"],
            Scope = { "user_birthday" },
            Fields = { "birthday", "picture" },
        });
```

In the AccountControllers ExternalLoginCallback method I was expecting to see the data for the picture in the ClaimsPrincipal collection which can be accessed via info.Principal but I cannot see any claim associated with picture.

Is this the right way to retrieve the Facebook user profile picture or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using 3rd Party Authentication, you are only get information about who user is (user authentication).

Using Facebook Authentication, after successful login you receive an access token to Facebook API and a collection of user data (claims) **only from** [UserInformationEndpoint](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/db7009531a23029e2516c52ca0d103149434f888/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook/FacebookDefaults.cs#L14) (https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me).

After that, you should call Facebook API methods if you want to get any  other user specific information (like user picture in your case - [Facebook Graph API. User Picture](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/)).

If you are interesting about claims that ASP.Core implementation of Facebook login is filled, looks into `CreateTicketAsync` method in [FacebookHandler](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook/FacebookHandler.cs) class - here the collection of claims is created.

Comment: Thanks Set for clarifying that the claims principal collection only contains data from the UserInformationEndpoint.

Comment: Can you point me to an example that shows how to call the facebook api methods

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442442/get-user-profile-picture-by-id

Comment: very unhelpful answer... doesn't explain anything about the Facebook auth middleware...

Answer (score 2):

For anyone using Microsoft' OWIN Facebook Authentication extensions. You can extend the default `FacebookAuthenticationProvider` to obtain any requested (and granted) claims to the current identity. Then register that customer provider in the middleware. A simple custom provider would look like this...

```
public class CustomFacebookOAuthProvider: FacebookAuthenticationProvider
    {
        public override Task Authenticated(FacebookAuthenticatedContext context)
        {
            if (context.User.IsNotNull() && context.Id.IsNotNullOrEmpty())
            {
                //ADD THE CLAIMS YOU WANT YOUR APP TO CONSUME
                context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(Constants.ClaimsTypes.PhotoUrl
                    , "https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/picture?height={1}&width={1}".With(context.Id, Constants.UI.DEFAUL_PROFILE_PICTURE_DIMENS)));
            }

            return base.Authenticated(context);
        }
    }
```

The implementation is simple, we only need to override the `Authenticated` method, which will be called once the OAuth provider (Facebook in this example) has authenticated the user and returned the user details (translate this to a call to the UserInfo endpoint).

The `context.User` is a `NewtonSoft.Json.JObject` which can be desrialized into your own class...

```
var user = context.User.ToObject<FacebookOAuthUser>();
```

Just make sure you create the `FacebookOAuthUser` class with the required properties.

Once you have that provider in place, all you need to do register it...

```
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = "Facebook",
    Caption = "Sign-in with Facebook",
    SignInAsAuthenticationType = signInAsType,
    AppId = ApplicationSettings.FacebookAppID,
    AppSecret = ApplicationSettings.FacebookAppSecret,
    Provider = new CustomFacebookOAuthProvider()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To get profile picture from Facebook, you need to configure Facebook options and subscribe at OnCreatingTicket event from OAuth.

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddFacebook("Facebook", options =>
                {

                    options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
                    options.ClientId = "ClientId";
                    options.ClientSecret = "ClientSecret";
                    options.Fields.Add("picture"); // <- Add field picture
                    options.Events = new OAuthEvents
                    {
                        OnCreatingTicket = context =>
                        {
                            var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)context.Principal.Identity;
                            var profileImg = context.User["picture"]["data"].Value<string>("url");
                            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Picture, profileImg));
                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        }
                    };
                });
```