# Using facebook pics as default pics for one's own website?

Tags: facebook

Apparently this question has already been answered.
Click the following link to follow through.
[Get user profile picture by Id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442442/get-user-profile-picture-by-id)

Answer (score 0):

Get the Facebook profile pictures using this link.

http://graph.facebook.com/" + facebookId + "/picture?type=square

For instance:
http://graph.facebook.com/67563683055/picture?type=square

There are also more sizes besides "square". See [the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/picture).

<sub>*This answer was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11442505/2408342).</sub>