# How can you get an access token for facebook using facebook login in asp.net identity?

Tags: facebook, asp.net-core

If you use Facebook login in an asp.net app, how would you go about getting the profile picture of a user?

It seems to me, from what I have gathered (reading)[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64434913/get-facebook-user-profile-image-after-facebook-changesoctober-24), that we need a user access token in order to get it - but when we have the user log in with facebook, we do not receive any kind of access token.

Is there a way to get the profile image just from the data/access you get when using facebook login - and how?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69980510/asp-net-identity-get-saved-third-party-access-tokens